# How to Execute Shell Script in C Programming, Receive Feedback and Processor ID, and Close Process

Tags: c, centos, fork, pid, child-process

I am writing a program that needs to fire another program for a number of seconds, then close it.

Feedback from the program's console would be useful, if possible.

I imagine I would close the program by retrieving the pid from the child process and running a pkill?

What would be the best way to go about this?

Thanks in advance

EDIT BY OP

```
void mountAd(char* adFilePath){

    char* mountPoint = getNextAvailableMount();

    // Set Playlist ready to be played
    editPlaylist(mountPoint, adFilePath);

    // Fork process and fire up ezstream
    int pid = fork();

    if(pid == 0){
        puts ("Child Process Here\n");
        execl ("/usr/local/bin/ezstream","/usr/local/bin/ezstream", "-c", "/home/hearme/radio/_test_adverts/advert01.xml", NULL);
        perror("execl");

    } else {
        puts ("Parent Process Here\n");
    }

    // Advised sleep for 3 seconds until ezstream has started
    sleep(3);

    // More stuff to do here later

    kill(pid, SIGTERM);
    waitpid(pid, NULL, 0);

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this should work:

```
pid = fork();
if (pid < 0)
    /* fork failed, error handling here */

if (pid == 0) {
    /* we are the child, exec process */
    execl(...);

    /* this is only reached if execl fails */
    perror("execl");

    /* do not use exit() here, do not return from main() */
    _Exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}

/* we are the parent */
sleep(duration);

kill(pid, SIGKILL);

/* use wait/waitpid/waitid as needed */
waitpid(pid, NULL, 0);
```

Notice that this does not correctly perform error checking for the case when the program you want to run cannot be found or executed, a more elaborate scheme is needed for that case, if you are interested I could elaborate.

Comment: I'll give that a shot. If i can clarify, the new child is fired when you call the fork()? When does the child process itself close? It looks like this will result in three processes, the parent, the fork process, and the program that is called by the fork process?

Comment: @GlennCooper `execl` does not create a new process, it replaces the forked process with a new process image. On UNIX, you do not “create processes,” you *fork* a process and then replace the process image with one of the `exec` functions.

Comment: Thus, this results in only two processes, the parent and the forked child.

Comment: Thanks @Fuzxxl: on that basis, if I called exec1 twice, what would happen to the first process image?

Comment: Perhaps a `SIGTERM` or `SIGINT` would do as well instead of hammering to dead the process via a `SIGKILL`?

Comment: @GlennCooper A successful call to execl doesn't return as the process image is replaced by a new one.

Comment: Hi, I've tested the above, the execl works fine, but neither SIGKILL or SIGTERM is working, see my edit above

Comment: @GlennCooper Please add this code to the question, not this answer. You modified my example incorrectly, a detailled edit follows when I'm at work.

Comment: @GlennCooper You copied my code incorrectly: The code inside the `if (pid == 0) { ... }` runs in the child, the other code runs in the parent. Why did you put the `kill` call (and basically everything else, too) in there? Only the `execl` call should be in there.

Comment: @FUZxxl - That worked once I moved it out of the IF statement, thanks your help

Comment: @FUZxxl - to add, my code actually continues with `perror` (it prints the consoled output from ezstream, whereas your answer states that this will only work if `execl` fails. Is my program showing correct behaviour?

Comment: @GlennCooper Your code is mostly correct, don't forget to call `_Exit()` in the child after `perror()`. The expected behaviour is that the `perror()` is only reached if the program cannot be executed. Thus you should either see the output of ezstream or the output of `perror()`.

Comment: @GlennCooper Also, use the type `pid_t` for process ids, not `int`.